# How to start a program with haswell-optimized libc?

Tags: centos7, glibc

Is there a way to start a program with haswell-optimized libc library on standard centos 7?

I prefer to do this without compiling myself.

Answer (score 2):

You invoke the program as follows:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/haswell_lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./program
```

Comment: question is shall I compile libc myself or there is already compiled version?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to that question.